# How can I purge and remove all network capabilities from Linux Mint?

Tags: networking, bluetooth

I have a fresh install of Linux Mint and the necessary software which I like to use.

I was now wondering how can I purge and remove all internet capabilities from my system, WiFi, Ethernet, Bluetooth - the whole lot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can blacklist the WiFi and Bluetooth drivers since they are loaded as modules. You'll need to modify for your specific drivers but you can use something similar to

```
#> cat >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf                                                                                                                                                                                               
blacklist rtw88_8821ce
install rtw88_8821ce /bin/false
^D
```

To disable the ethernet interfaces you will need to add a rule to udev. For eth0, add this rule to `etc/udev/rules.d/90-disable-eth0.rules`

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ENV{ID_NET_NAME_ONBOARD}=="eth0", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys$DEVPATH/device/remove'"
```

Modify as necessary for your particular interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Compile a custom kernel, disable all networking/wifi/ethernet/bluetooth functionality for this kernel.